# Can't connect to SugarCRM Soap API

Tags: soap, c#-3.0, sugarcrm

I've just started on a project where I need to insert contacts into a SugarCRM system using the SOAP interface.

So far I have created a reference to the service http://sugar-dev.walkinwifi.net/soap.php?wsdl=sugarsoap

Then writen some code like this

```
public SugarHelper()
    {
        //Create a new instance of the client proxy
        this.sugarClient = new sugarsoapPortTypeClient();

        //Set the default value
        this.sessionId = String.Empty;
    }

    public bool Authenticate(string Username, string Password)
    {
        //Create an authentication object
        user_auth user = new user_auth();

        //Set the credentials
        user.user_name = Username;
        user.password = this.computeMD5String(Password);

        //Try to authenticate
        set_entry_result authentication_result = this.sugarClient.login(user, "");
```

this gives you the jest.

The last line gives me an exception when login is called.

The exception I get has an inner exception complaining it can't connect to https://sugar-dev.walkinwifi.net/soap.php

```
{"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://sugar-dev.walkinwifi.net/soap.php. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."}
```

Where does the https part come from? I have used no other reference other than http yet the error clearly states https.

Can I connect to SugarCRM soap via http or must I use https?

In all the examples I can find on the net it's http but most of them are php with very c# ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking in the wrong place.  Inside the Soap configuration of Sugar you specify the url that will be used for soap calls.  This is set to https://sugar-dev.walkinwifi.com.

Changed it to http and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, the SOAP services must also work over HTTPS. Personally I have not had any problems, even with a C # client. Verify that the server certificate and the certificate chain are valid.

Bye,
Antonio.

Comment: C# SOAP Client for accessing Web Services exposed by SugarCRM. The client version of the framework is based on .NET 4 https://github.com/amusarra/SugarCRMCSharpSOAPClient